# Having trouble with http-server ,the computer keeps downloading the file and not loading the html file I need

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http, babeljs

I tried created a server to load a html file when I use javascript with Babel, I follow the instruction: I download Node.js, then npm install http-server, then copy the path into command prompt as "http-server [path] " then command prompt return "Starting up http-server, etc.. Available on "127.0.0.1" but when I enter it into the  browser, the browser keep asking me to download the file into computer and not loading anything in the screen. Every step I follow is okay except the last part, I stuck at it for days, please help, I am having serious trouble with my company because of it, I never have it before.

I tried:
-Check the path to the file into my computer, doesnt work.
-Re install http-server
-Watching several tutorial on youtube, each step i exactly the same, except the last and most important part, the file just not loading and keep downloading that file again into my laptop.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow community. It is better include a minimal reproducible example. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Danizavtz I think there's no code in the world to implement the problem, as Http-Server is a command line server.

Comment: Yes , there are no code involved here, in fact I wish it had code , if anybody clearly read this, it is apparently I not even write the code on it because of that